Java List.of() as key in HashMap?
I know that in general, you should only use immutable objects as a key to a hashmap since if their address or their contents change, then the hash breaks. This is one of the reasons why a normal List shouldn't be used as a key to a hashmap in Java. However, the function List.of() returns an immutable list.
Is it good practice to use lists returned by List.of() as keys in a HashMap?

It really depends on what is in the list, and whether or not that is also immutable, not so much on whether or not you should use an immutable list or not.

The List might contain a mutable object (the internal state of the object can change), thinking about the possibility of this I think it might not be good to use.

@AzizGasimov Assuming my list contains wrapper classes like String, Integer, Character, etc would this be a perfectly valid way of doing it since I believe all of those classes are also immutable?

What is the usecase to use a complex object for an unique key?

@CodingMike like lance-java said in his answer below, as long as the list is effectively immutable, including its contents, then you can use it in a HashMap safely. Since List.of produces unmodifiable lists and your contents are immutable, your use case is allowed.

"in general" i would not use objects as "key to a hashmap", which don't have constant (time/change) + very efficient + collision free "hash(+equals!) functions" (..but you can neglect/tolerate on smaller hashmaps), ...for the standard implementations of List.of() the "cons(is)tancy condition" would  not hold, so for "big maps" (~2Gig), i would recommend to implement the hash/key functions (ever) manually/with care

You can use any object you like as a key in a HashMap so long as hashCode() and equals(Object) abide by the equals / hashCode contract. So it's perfectly acceptable to use List as a key, even better to use List.of(...) since the list is immutable (although items in the list are still open for mutation).
As you have mentioned, you can't legally mutate the key after it's been put into the HashMap. If you do the HashMap will have unexpected behavior since the Entry will be allocated a bucket that no longer matches it's hashCode()

I would replace "valid" with "stable" or "consistent", seeing as a mutable object will still produce valid hash codes. The results should not change, especially the hashCode(), for the reasons you mentioned.

List.of(...) being immutable does not make it a good key. If the elements are mutable, mutating any one of them will break the map. Check the docs for the formula used.

I said "even better to use List.of(...) since the list is immutable (although items in the list are still open for mutation)" and "you can't legally mutate the key after it's been put into the HashMap". I'm not sure how your comment helps?

I would rather call the object returned by List.of() "unchangeable".  When List.of() was first introduced they called it "immutable" in the documentation, but then they realized this is wrong, so in later JDK versions they changed the documentation to read "unmodifiable" instead of "immutable".  However, the term "unmodifiable" is also an unfortunate choice, because the term already had a meaning, via "unmodifiableListOf()", which stands for an "unmodifiable to you view of my list, which is still very mutable, and any mutations I make to it will be very visible to you."
